# How to find how many external IP addresses are part of communications in a captured file using wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

I am trying to use wireshark to find out how many external IP addresses are part of the communications that were previously captured. Is there any way of finding this out using filters or the statistics menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line is your friend:

```
$ tshark -r dump.pcap | awk '{ print $3 }' | sort | uniq -c
602 a.b.c.d
  7 A.B.C.D
669 W.X.Z.Y
```

GUI people should use menu option:

```
Statistics->Endpoints
```